# How to always show annotation?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotationview

In my mapView, I have annotations that are shown as `MKMarkerAnnotationView`.

I set their `clusteringIdentifier` to `nil` to force them not to cluster.

However, when I zoom out, if two annotations are close to each other, instead of clustering, one of them just disappears.

How can I force all fo the annotations that are `MKMarkerAnnotationView` to show even when zoomed out?

Answer (score 0):

since iOS 11 you can set `displayPriority`of your `MKMarkerAnnotationView` to `.required`

Comment: When I made this post last year `MKMarkerAnnotationView` had a bug where the `displayPriority` that you set wasn't being reflected when the code ran. The issue was fixed promptly by Apple.